# Strange issue with 2 initializers in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, initialization

I want to create 2 initializers for my custom button class which looks like:

```
protocol CustomButtonProtocol {
    var title: String { get set }
    var cornerRadius: CGFloat { get set }
    var backgroundColor: UIColor { get set }
}

struct Button: CustomButtonProtocol {
    var title: String
    var cornerRadius: CGFloat
    var backgroundColor: UIColor
}

class CustomButton: UIButton {
var title: String? {
    didSet {
        self.setTitle(title, for: .normal)
    }
}

var cornerRadius: CGFloat = 0.0 {
    didSet {
        self.layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
    }
}

var color: UIColor? {
    didSet {
        self.backgroundColor = color
    }
}

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
}

init(with frame: CGRect, button: Button) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    self.title = button.title
    self.cornerRadius = button.cornerRadius
    self.backgroundColor = button.backgroundColor
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
}
```

I want to have 2 initializers, the first one is simple init, the second one with my `Button` passed in, but the issue is that it changes ONLY background color but does not `title` and `cornerRadius` properties and I cannot find why it happens. Maybe I do not see something, could you please help me with finding the bug?

Comment: `cornerRadius` also required `masksToBounds = true`

Comment: Instead of using `self.cornerRadius` use `self.layer.cornerRadius` and add one more line for corner radius `self.layer.masksToBounds = true`

Comment: @Tj3n does not work. Neither `title`, nor `cornerRadius`

Answer (score 1):

Consider that property observers `willSet / didSet` are not called  in `init` methods

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html):

> When you assign a default value to a stored property, or set its initial value within an initializer, the value of that property is set directly, without calling any property observers.

A solution is to call the code in the observers also in the init method

```
init(with frame: CGRect, button: Button) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    self.title = button.title
    self.setTitle(self.title, for: .normal)
    self.cornerRadius = button.cornerRadius
    self.layer.cornerRadius = self.cornerRadius
    self.color = button.backgroundColor
    self.backgroundColor = self.color
}
```

If `color` represents always the background color the property is actually redundant.

Comment: Then why does backgroundColor change ?

Comment: @Nitish `backgroundColor` is not a stored property of the subclass.

Answer (score 1):

You have used `didSet` to update value to button property.

It won't call `didSet` while setting value inside `init`.

background color is getting set because you set `backgroundColor` by mistake in place of `color`

```
self.backgroundColor = button.backgroundColor
```

you should use/call below inside/outside `init` once.

```
self.setTitle(title, for: .normal)
self.layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
self.backgroundColor = color
```

Comment: thanks for the answer! I did not get this part `background color is getting set because you set backgroundColor by mistake in place of color`, could you please explain it?

Comment: @J.Doe you have used `self.backgroundColor = button.backgroundColor` in place of `self.color = button.backgroundColor` by mistake probabliy. If you would have wrote `self.color = button.backgroundColor`, in your initial implementation, background color would not be there.